# Vertically aligning text to a circle

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, geometry

I am trying to vertically align some text to a circle having a shape-outside property.

I am looking for a pure css solution.

See jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dybt94ds/

```css
.wrap {
height: 220px;
width: 400px;
}

.circly {
background: red;
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
border-radius: 50%;
float: left;
shape-outside: circle();
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<div class="circly"></div>
<div class="text">
 I am lots of text. I should always be verticly centered to the middle of the circle.
</div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
<div class="circly"></div>
<div class="text">
 I am lots of text. I should always be verticly centered to the middle of the circle. I am lots of text. I should always be verticly centered to the middle of the circle.
</div>
</div>


<div class="wrap">
<div class="circly"></div>
<div class="text">
 I am lots of text. I should always be verticly centered to the middle of the circle. I am lots of text. I should always be verticly centered to the middle of the circle. I am lots of text. I should always be verticly centered to the middle of the circle.
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you ok with a solution that includes some javascript?

Comment: Would prefer without.

Answer (score 2):

js to the rescue... Calculate the top padding for the text by retrieving the text `div` offset height.

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('text');
for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  var pad = (200 - elements[i].offsetHeight) / 2;
  elements[i].style.paddingTop = pad + "px";
}
```

```css
.wrap {
  height: 220px;
  width: 400px;
}

.circly {
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
  shape-outside: circle();
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="circly"></div>
  <div class="text">
    I am lots of text. I should always be verticly centered to the middle of the circle.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="circly"></div>
  <div class="text">
    I am lots of text. I should always be verticly centered to the middle of the circle. I am lots of text. I should always be verticly centered to the middle of the circle.
  </div>
</div>


<div class="wrap">
  <div class="circly"></div>
  <div class="text">
    I am lots of text. I should always be verticly centered to the middle of the circle. I am lots of text. I should always be verticly centered to the middle of the circle. I am lots of text. I should always be verticly centered to the middle of the circle.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Pre-flex, dynamic vertical alignment was one of the major pain points of CSS, so without it (or JS), what you're asking verges on impossible. If JS is an option you can adjust the spacing dynamically (ES6 because it works in browsers `shape-outline` does):

**EDIT** Update on the viability of common CSS vertical centering methods:

- As stated in the MDN docs, `shape-outside`, applies only to floated elements. This would seem to imply that the text must remain in flow with element you want to apply the shaping to. As far as I can tell, this limits you to only interacting with `margin` and `padding` properties, because of how positioning effects the text flow. Since the height is not fixed on your text block, you cannot use that value in `calc` property. In short, your text container *must* be statically positioned and `display: block`.
- Text wrapping is calculated prior to `position: relative` and `transform`, so those are of no use.
- Table cells treat all content of a cell as a single block (for centering), so the text is aligned to the top of the circle, which is vertically centered.

This would seem to eliminate every CSS-only vertical centering method as a candidate (that I'm aware of).

```
document.querySelectorAll('.text').forEach((text) => {
  text.style.paddingTop = `${(200 - text.clientHeight)/2}px`;
});
```

Comment: How exactly this answer gives anything that isn't already exists in the answer by jfeferman?

Comment: Added somewhat exhaustive dissection of why various methods (that I tried) won't work

Comment: Lovely ES6 solution! Perhaps the question is, and sorry to be blunt: why not just go with js and get on with life... I know, I'm also fervently in favor of all the wonderful things pure CSS3 gives us. But then again, it is CSS, and the web is made up of a conjunction of technologies. I would be hard pressed to find a web resource that doesn't use js to try to force browsers into submission, IMHO.

Comment: @jfeferman I agree; I understand the desire to achieve the elegance of a CSS pure solution (spent far too much time on it myself haha), but dealing with such an experimental set of properties, the practicality of pure CSS reaches a limit. As far as I can tell, given the interplay of different aspects of CSS, a pure CSS solution is, at this point, fundamentally unachievable.

Comment: "why not just go with js?" because you would see the text jump after the js executed. of course you could hide it and only show it after the js ran, but that would be a shortcoming - but maybe the only option.

Comment: Well aware of the short comings of JS solution, but it's my professional conclusion the CSS solution you seek is fundamentally infeasible given current implementation of the CSS properties. If you want to avoid snapping, you could use `transition` to achieve a smooth animation.

Answer (score -2):

It's solved by from my side. I have applied old classic table structure layout as applying display:table to parent and display:table-cell and vertical-align:middle to child divs.

```
.wrap {
    height: 220px;
    width: 400px;
  display :table;
}

.circly {
    background: red;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    float: left;
    shape-outside: circle();
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.text {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

This was only preferred solution from my end! Hope this works!

Comment: Unfortunately this method wont let the text flow around the circle.